# mysql: is mysql_real_connect required in this case?

Tags: mysql

https://github.com/hholzgra/connector-c-examples/blob/master/mysql_real_escape_string.c

I'm just trying to use the mysql_real_escape_string function of mysql and have tried the above usage example. The mysql doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html says that "Client programs must successfully connect to a server before executing any other API functions that require a valid MYSQL connection handler structure". **However I tried this without the mysql_real_connect and it also seems to work**.
Here is the mysql_real_escape_string doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html
Is the mysql_real_connect really needed in this case? Is it not required because I'm not actually performing some DB operation and was simply using a lib str manipulation function?

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string()`? If you want to prevent SQL injections, use prepared statements.

Comment: @Progman The question says they're not doing any database queries.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> The `mysql` argument must be a valid, open connection because character escaping depends on the character set in use by the server.

So you have to connect to the server so it can determine which characters need to be escaped. It's not intended as a general-purpose escaping library, it's specific to the escaping needed by MySQL.

And it's preferable not to use this even if you do have a connection. Prepared statements with parameters are a much better way to prevent SQL injection than escaping.